# How can i pass array from android to php using url encode?

Tags: android, database, insert, urlencode

I'm using the post method to get data from android to php and URLEncode to encode the data from android to php. My problem with this method is that when inserting multiple queries it takes a lot of time depending on how many i will insert in a loop. So what i want to happen now is to pass array to php then the php will do the inserting

Comment: You might want to do a POST instead of a url-encoded get request. Either way, wrap it in json and send it across.

Comment: Can u give me a specific code to the one you're referring? I'm not not really familiar with POST method and How do i wrap it in json and send it across?

Comment: Google really helps you here. I gave you all the search words, I'm not going to write the app for you.